# vscode clangd cannot index cuda header files outside of .cu files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cuda, clang, clangd

I'd like to use vscode clangd to index CUDA header files in my project. However, it won't run correctly when I am not in `.cu` files, even the content of them are the same.

[image]

[image]

I wonder if there is any way to make it run correctly? Thanks.

- clangd version:Ubuntu clangd version 16.0.4
- vscode-clangd version:v0.1.24
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

I've already add `-I/usr/local/cuda-12.1/targets/x86_64-linux/include` into vscode-clangd settings in Fallback Flags.